# java.awt.Frame.setBackground(Color arg0) not displaying PINK color

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I am trying to run below programs which should display background color PINK and String "This is a test." in White

1) Test.java

```
package Practice;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800,600,16,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
        Test test = new Test();
        test.run(dm);
    }

    public void run(DisplayMode dm){

        setBackground(Color.PINK);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));

        Screen s = new Screen();

        try{
            s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }finally{
            s.restoreScreen();
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.drawString("This is a test.", 200, 200);
    }
}
```

2) Screen.java

```
package Practice;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Screen {

    private GraphicsDevice videoCard;

    public Screen(){

        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        videoCard = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    }

    public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window){

        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        videoCard.setFullScreenWindow(window);

        if(dm != null && videoCard.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
            try{
                videoCard.setDisplayMode(dm);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public Window getFullScreenWindow(){

        return videoCard.getFullScreenWindow();
    }

    public void restoreScreen(){

        Window w = videoCard.getFullScreenWindow();

        if(w != null){

            w.dispose();
        }

        videoCard.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    }

}
```

**Expected Result :**

Full screen displaying background color PINK and String "This is a test." in   White

**Actual Result :**

Full screen displaying background color BLACK and String "This is a test." in   White.

I am running this in eclipse on Windows machine.

Comment: Don't set frame's background and foreground. Graphics object in paint method does not take care of frame background or foreground. You have to set color to your graphics object (`g.setColor (Color.PINK);`). Also, **never** override paint method (use `paintComponent`, instead), and don't do it in your frame class. You could do all your paint stuff in a class which extends JPanel (in `paintComponent` method), then you add that panel to your frame.

Comment: @Ansharja well, i currently have this two classes only. After setting graphics object (g.setColor (Color.PINK);). also i am getting same issue.

Comment: Are you setting graphics color *before* drawing your string?

Comment: i tried both before and after, but in before case : my fonts are changed and not the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the first comment, there are a lot of things you should not do:

- You should not directly use `JFrame` to make some custom painting. Instead, use a `JPanel`. There is also no need in this case to extend `JFrame`, you are not adding any feature.
- To change frame's background color, you should better set the background color of the frame's content pane. Also, to change the color used to draw a string, you should call `Graphics.setColor ()`.
- Don't override `paint` method. Instead, override `JComponent's` `paintComponent` method. Also, the first line in your method should call the parent paint method, to allow the component to paint itself normally before doing anything else.

Finally, it's not clear what you want to do inside your `Screen` class, but calling `Thread.sleep` there is actually a bad practice, and to me all that code does not make much sense.

The best way to enable full screen mode is to call `setExtendedState (JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` on your frame.

This is a working example of what i said:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String [] a) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
            @Override public void run () {
                createAndShowGUI ();
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("App");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane (new DrawPanel (Color.PINK, Color.WHITE));
        frame.pack ();
        // frame.setExtendedState (JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // You can use this instruction to have full screen mode.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{
    Color foregroundColor;

    public DrawPanel (Color backgroundColor, Color foregroundColor) {
        setBackground (backgroundColor);
        this.foregroundColor = foregroundColor;
    }
    @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
        return new Dimension (400, 400);
    }
    @Override protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent (g);
        g.setColor (foregroundColor);
        g.setFont (new Font ("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        g.drawString ("This is a test.", 200, 200);
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]